# React Native Fetch on Android will not pass options

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I can't seem to get Android to pass any options when it works fine on iOS. It appears to go to the endpoint and drop the method, headers and body. I don't know for sure because when I added some of the code I mention below to debug, it works.

```
let data = JSON.stringify({
    appKeyLookup: CONSTANTS.APP_KEY_LOOKUP,
    username: username,
    password: password,
});
try {
    let response = await fetch(CONSTANTS.API_URL + 'login/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        },
        body: data,
    });
    let responseJSON = await response.json();
```

The really weird thing is, that if I add

```
const _XHR = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?  GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest : GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest            
XMLHttpRequest = _XHR
```

To the entry point and then install the chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

It works fine. So it seems it has something to do with CORS but I am not sure.

I am on React Native 0.56.0

Comment: Another difference with this project over my past is that I am using VSCode + React Native Tools. However to launch the Android Version I am doing it through Android Studio and running react-native start in terminal.

Comment: Still having issues with this on 0.57.7. It seems I don't actually need the CORS extension but need to make sure to add the _XHR code and have Remote JS Debugging enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. Android is appending 'charset=utf-8' to the Content-Type. Making it 'Content-Type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'. This is causing issues with the API I am using. I was completely wrong when I thought it was stripping the body.

I found this out from [React-Native appends "charset=utf-8" to HTTP call Content-Type](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8237) which has lead me to two different fixes.

[Java Fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13487#issuecomment-319984503)

Or

[JavaScript Fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14445#issuecomment-352965210)